# Can i pass different form data types using covariance in scala?

Tags: forms, scala, types, playframework, covariance

In the same way that the [documentation for covariance](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html) states that:

> For some class List[+A], making A covariant implies that for two types
>   A and B where A is a subtype of B, then List[A] is a subtype of
>   List[B]

Can this also be applied to `Form` (as in *scala forms*)? I'm having issues passing forms of various type. Here's a sample of what I'm doing:

```
   abstract class SuperCovariance

   case class TestCovariance1(id: Option[Int], name: String, another: String) extends SuperCovariance

   case class TestCovariance2(id: Option[Int], differentName: String, other: String) extends SuperCovariance

   object Tc1Form {

     val form = Form(
       mapping(
         "_id" -> optional(number),
         "name" -> nonEmptyText,
         "another" -> nonEmptyText
       )(TestCovariance1.apply)(TestCovariance1.unapply)
     )

   }

   object Tc2Form {

     val form = Form(
       mapping(
         "_id" -> optional(number),
         "differentName" -> nonEmptyText,
         "other" -> nonEmptyText
       )(TestCovariance2.apply)(TestCovariance2.unapply)
     )

   }
```

If either one of the forms can be passed as a parameter in a method I thought that I could do this:

```
     def acceptAnySubTypeOfSuperCovariance(myForm: Form[SuperCovariance])(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]): Result = {
       Ok(views.html.myTemplate(myForm))
     }
```

Calling this method and passing a `Form[TestCovariance1]` type causes an error which is causing me an issue in understanding and how to avoid writing such methods for each subtype of `SuperCovariance`. Any help/enlightenment welcome!

---

To clarify my reasoning for wanting to be able to do this - it is in order to avoid writing duplicating lines of code for each form. So if I have multiple forms I would prefer to have one method in the *controller* which binds the data from the request, e.g.

```
   def updateDoc(collectionName: String, oId: Option[BSONObjectID]) = Action.async { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>

       MyModel.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
         errorForm => Future.successful(Ok(views.html.errorTemplate(errorForm, MyModel)),
         data => {

           val updatedDoc = ?? // map data to model here, e.g. TestCovariance1(None, data.name, data.another)

           // calls a method 
           updateMultipleFields[MyModel](collectionName, updatedDoc, oId).map(x =>
             Redirect(routes.DatabaseC.editIndex(collName, oId.get))
           )

         }
       )
   }

  // generic method to update fields in collection (Mongo database)
  def updateMultipleFields[T](collectionName: String, model: T, id: Option[BSONObjectID])(implicit writes: Writer[T]): Future[Result] = {

    val idSelector = Json.obj("_id" -> id)
    getCollection(collectionName).flatMap(collection =>
      collection.update(idSelector, Json.obj("$set" -> model)).map {
        lastError =>
          Created("fields updated")
      }
    )

  }
```

I thought that an MVC structure would be flexible in allowing me to set up the handling of data in such a way that if done correctly (and safely); I would be able to simply add data by creating new models (forms & models). If I cannot; it doesn't prevent the functionality of the application but it just seems that repeating these kinds of *boiler plate*-like code is one of the reasons why Scala exists.

Comment: What's the error thrown? I think you don't need to enforce covariance in this case.

Comment: @nicodp the error is - *Type mismatch, expected: Form[SuperCovariance], expected: Form[TestCovariance1] *

Comment: sorry - typo: *Type mismatch, expected: Form[SuperCovariance], actual: Form[TestCovariance1] *

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that what the link you mention references can be used in your example. For that to work the `Form` class itself should have been declared as covariant in `T` `Form[+T]` and they could not do it because it is used for transformation in both directions.  Still you probably can do something like you want by

```
 def acceptAnySubTypeOfSuperCovariance[T:<SuperCovariance](myForm: Form[T])(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]): Result =
```

However this code makes my wonder: do you really want to pass `Form[some subclass of SuperCovariance]`? What does your `acceptAnySubTypeOfSuperCovariance` really do that you want to do so? Usuaully it makes more sense to bind the data from the request and get the object and then pass it around. And this will work without the need for generics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (& sorry for the delay in responding). I have edited my original question above so hopefully this will make it a little clearer as to why I would like to do this.